# maven downloading from wrong repository

Tags: java, maven, build, bamboo

In one of the project build run on Bamboo server , it looks like mvn goes to download certain parent pom ( of the currently building project ) - but the repository it looks into is the wrong one - the build fails because the resource is not there. I don't know how to tell mvn on the Bamboo server to look at a particular url for any downloads - conversely - where should I investigate to find out why mvn is looking at this wrong url ?  If I run a local mvn clean install it works fine because I know the urls are specified in my settings.xml.

Also , is this url setting specific to projects on Bamboo ( ie - each project can specify its own url for maven to look when downloading ) ?

Answer (score 3):

Older versions of Maven would sometimes report very misleading pathnames.

You need to check:

1. are there any `<repository>` elements in your poms?
2. are there any repositories or mirrors declared in the global configuration file?
3. Is bamboo configured to use a different set of repositories or mirrors than you usually use?

Answer (score 0):

We can specify the repository in pom.xml iself, for more information refer the below link

http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-remote-repository-in-maven-pom-xml/

Working in local may be because of all the necessary jars available in your local repository.

Comment: I want to specifically know why Maven is using this particular (wrong) url for downloading - do you know how I can find out that ? Any settings on bamboo server ? my own POMs do not specify any repository section.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have a ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml. If you do, then your Bamboo server might not be configured with that settings.xml that includes your repository, see http://maven.apache.org/settings.html.

Looking for lines like the following in the build log can help troubleshoot which repository is being used:
Downloading: "http://yourmvnhost:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/maven-metadata.xml"